# SSMS Linked Server -ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms, oracle-12c, tnsnames

How could I use "Linked Server" from SSMS IDE to connect the Oracle server database with "SYSDBA"?

I've tried many methods as following to show you what I did right now:
Oracle client connect to Oracle Server data:

[image]

SSMS connect to Oracle Server data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

More testing information
I also use "SQLPLUS" to check *tnsnames.ora* the file is okay or not but the answer is as following

1. sqlplus SYS/Oradoc_db1@DBNAME as SYSDBA <-- is okay
2. sqlplus SYS/Oradoc_db1@DBNAME <-- Error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to connect as SYS? In general,  that is a big no-no.

Comment: @MichaelKutz sorry I don't know what do you mean "SYS" <-- it is the username

Comment: @MichaelKutz I have added another content with SQLPLUS, hopefully you can know more about my issue,thanks

Comment: "SYS" is an administrator account that should not be used for normal activities.  Why are you trying to connect as SYS? What are you trying to do as SYS that can't be done with a non-SYS account with the DBA role?

Comment: @MichaelKutz Thanks I see,I use a original oracle container with docker,in fact I didn’t change anything on my server side but my problem is ROLE not account , please help to deal with this issue please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and you can follow my steps to fix this issue.
1. Don't use SYS to be your USERID
2. Add new USERID

```
-- CREATE USER SQL
1. CREATE USER a
2. IDENTIFIED BY a
3. DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
4. TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";
*** <-- if you got the error, please follow above content to fix problem
 (SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;  )
-- ROLES
GRANT DBA TO a;
```